# SEO impact of using one image for several different posts on my site

Tags: seo, images, website-design, google-ranking

What is the impact of using one image for several post on my site?
 Does it have a negative affect on SEO? For several posts, I use one picture. because all of them are Q & A. Am I wrong? is it bad for SEO?

Comment: Are you talking about SEO for the posts in web search, or for the images in image search?

Answer (score 3):

Using the same image in several places isn't necessarily bad. I think it can actually be good UX if you use it for a recurring type of post. That way, your users will easily recognize this type of post while scrolling down your blog.

In terms of SEO I would consider if you can make the image more specific to each post and/or keyword (if that's possible with your post titles). For example, you might consider changing the ALT tag on a per-post basis or even download the image, change its title and re-upload it for each post so you can use different keywords.

Comment: I have seen exactly the same image have ranked for various low competition keywords, just by changing the alt tag. If it competitive keyword then best use a different image.